# How to install a lua module in a subdirectory of libdir with the autotools

Tags: lua, makefile, autotools, configure

I have written a little lua module that I complile using the autotools and I want to modify its organization:

Now I have this in the main directory:

```
autogen.sh
configure.ac
Makefile.am
src
    file1.c
    file2.c
    file3.c
```

the **autogen.sh**

```
 #!/bin/sh
 echo "Running aclocal..." ; aclocal $ACLOCAL_FLAGS || exit 1
 echo "Running libtoolize..."; libtoolize --copy --automake || exit 1;
 echo "Running autoheader..." ; autoheader || exit 1
 echo "Running autoconf..." ; autoconf || exit 1
 echo "Running automake..." ; automake --add-missing --copy --gnu || exit 1
 ./configure "$@"
```

The **configure.ac**

```
#                                               -*- Autoconf -*-
# Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([lua-clangc], [0.0.1], [cedlemo@gmx.com])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([configure.ac])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CC(clang gcc)
# Checks for libraries.
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([DEPS], [lua])
#LUA_VERSION = $(pkg-config --version)
#AC_SUBST([LUA_VERSION])
# Checks for header files.
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([string.h stdlib.h clang-c/Index.h])
# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
# Checks for library functions.
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(1.13 dist-bzip2 foreign subdir-objects)
LT_PREREQ(2.4)
LT_INIT
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
  Makefile
])
AC_OUTPUT
```

and the **Makefile.am**

```
MAINTAINERCLEANFILES = \
Makefile.in aclocal.m4 config.h.in configure \
depcomp install-sh missing compile config.sub \
config.guess ltmain.sh compile

lib_LTLIBRARIES = src/clangc.la
src_clangc_la_SOURCES = src/clangc.c src/indexlib.c src/translationunitlib.c src/constants.c src/clangc_module_functions.c
src_clangc_la_LDFLAGS = -module -avoid-version -shared -llua -lm -lclang -fPIC
```

I use this commands to compile and install the lua module:

```
./autogen.sh --libdir=/usr/lib/lua/5.3
make
sudo make install
```

My files are installed in /usr/lib/lua/5.3

```
/usr/lib/lua/5.3/clangc.so
/usr/lib/lua/5.3/clangc.la
```

I would like to just use

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
```

And that the configure.ac script build libdir like this:

```
libdir=prefix + /lib/lua/ + LUA_VERSION + /clangc/
```

(I have already a way to get the LUA_VERSION in the configure.ac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always I answer to myself:

I just have to modify my configure.ac like this:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([lua-clangc], [0.0.1], [cedlemo@gmx.com])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([configure.ac])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CC(clang gcc)

# Checks for libraries.
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([DEPS], [lua])
LUA_VERSION=$(pkg-config --modversion lua | awk -F "." '{print $1"."$2}')
AC_SUBST([LUA_VERSION])

libdir=$prefix/lib/lua/$LUA_VERSION/clangc
# Checks for header files.
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([string.h stdlib.h clang-c/Index.h])

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.

# Checks for library functions.
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(1.13 dist-bzip2 foreign subdir-objects)
LT_PREREQ(2.4)
LT_INIT
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
  Makefile
])
AC_OUTPUT
```

First I had to find the current lua version:

```
LUA_VERSION=$(pkg-config --modversion lua | awk -F "." '{print $1"."$2}')
```

On my system:

- pkg-config --modversion lua returns *5.3.1*
- awk -F "." '{print $1"."$2}' returns *5.3*

Then the line:

```
libdir=$prefix/lib/lua/$LUA_VERSION/clangc
```

Do all the magic.

When I use:

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
```

My lib is installed in:

```
/usr/lib/lua/5.3/clangc
```